# alpine.js - button in loop / click multiple times fired

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am new to alpine.js and have a strange behaviour. What am i doing wrong?
The button action "removePerson()" is always executed twice. I have no idea - why ?

```
<template x-for="(person, i) in persons" :key="i">
  <div class="mt-3">
    <label>Name <span x-text="i"></span></label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Namen eingeben" x-model="person.name">
      <template x-if="i <= persons.length">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <button type="button" @click.prevent="removePerson(i)" class="btn btn-primary">remove</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

More in detail:
https://codepen.io/derrobert/pen/Yzypzej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove template tag  and keep elements inside it

```
<template x-if="i <= persons.length">
</template>
```

see your code live
https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/yLYVYYB?editors=1010

Comment: +1 - great - but may i ask one last question:
if i add persons i am unable to remove the last existing one.
Lets say i add 3 persons and click "Remove" from bottom to top. Then the 1st element always stays visible although the counter days "0".
This confuses me. Any help or hint would be great

Comment: the only template statement you need is the `x-for` template so remove other template for that set of elements